# Sprite not showing when drawn

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am attempting to build an android game using LibGDX. This is my first android app, so forgive me if what I am asking for is simple. I am trying to draw a sprite, but nothing seems to show up. I was thinking that maybe the sprite is drawn outside of the camera space, but even when I take the camera back(showing out of game area), I can't see the sprite. I have spent quite a while trying to find the problem, and I have not been able to. This is my Playstate Class:

```
public class PlayState extends State{
    private Man man;
    private Cannon cannon;
    private Texture cannontop;
    private Texture bg;
    private SpriteBatch sb;

    public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        cannon = new Cannon();
        cannontop = new Texture("Cannon.png");
        man = new Man(0, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 4));
        bg = new Texture("background.png");
        cam.setToOrtho(false, 2160, 3840);

    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {
       // finish later

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        man.update(dt);
        //cannon.update();
    }

    public void create(){
        sb = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(bg, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2), 0);
        sb.draw(man.getTexture(), man.getPosition().x, man.getPosition().y);
        //sb.draw(cannon.getTexture(), cannon.getPositionx(), cannon.getPositiony());
        cannon.getCannon().draw(sb);
        sb.draw(cannontop, (bg.getWidth()/ 2) - (cannon.getTextureWidth() / 2) - 23, (bg.getHeight() / 2) + (bg.getHeight() / 5));
        //sb.draw(cannon.getTexture(), (bg.getWidth()/ 2) - (cannon.getTextureWidth() / 2), (bg.getHeight() / 2) + (bg.getHeight() / 5) - (cannontop.getWidth() / 2) + 8);
        sb.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        bg.dispose();
        man.dispose();
        cannon.dispose();
    }
}
```

The sprite that I am trying to draw is in the cannon class. This is my cannon class:

```
public class Cannon {
    private Texture cannend;
    private Texture bg;
    private Texture cannonmain;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Sprite cannon;


    public Cannon(){
        cannonmain = new Texture("Cannon.png");
        bg = new Texture ("background.png");
        cannend = new Texture("cannonend.png");
        cannon = new Sprite(cannend, (bg.getWidth()/ 2) - (cannend.getWidth() / 2), (bg.getHeight() / 2) + (bg.getHeight() / 5) - (cannonmain.getWidth() / 2) + 8, (cannend.getWidth()), (cannend.getHeight()));
        cannon.setPosition((bg.getWidth()/ 2) - (cannend.getWidth() / 2), (bg.getHeight() / 2) + (bg.getHeight() / 5) - (cannonmain.getWidth() / 2) + 8);
        cannon.setRotation(70);
        cannon.setCenter((bg.getWidth()/ 2) , (bg.getHeight() / 2) + (bg.getHeight() / 5) + 3*(cannend.getHeight() / 4));
    }
    //public update(dt){
    //    stuffff
    // }


    public Sprite getCannon(){
        return cannon;
    }

    public float getPositionx(){
        return cannon.getX();
    }

    public float getPositiony(){
        return cannon.getY();
    }

    public void dispose(){
        cannonmain.dispose();
        cannend.dispose();
        bg.dispose();
    }

    public Texture getTexture(){
        return cannend;
    }

    public float getTextureWidth(){
        return cannend.getWidth();
    }
}
```

I apologise is the sprite/texture names are confusing. Please ignore the comments, as they are there for the future/alternative things that I have tried. I would like to know what I could do to get the Sprite to appear. Also, would the sprite rotate after I make it appear? Any help is massively appreciated.
Thanks.

state class:

```
public abstract class State {
    protected OrthographicCamera cam;
    protected Vector3 mouse;
    protected GameStateManager gsm;

    protected State(GameStateManager gsm) {
        this.gsm = gsm;
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        mouse = new Vector3();

    }


    protected abstract void handleInput();
    public abstract void update(float dt);
    public abstract void render(SpriteBatch sb);
    public abstract void dispose();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should draw your sprites with `sprite.draw(spritebatch)`, instead of `spritebatch.draw(sprite)`.

Also, what's the use of the State class? Is Playstate supposed to be a screen? Then you should probably implement the Screen interface in your class, which will then use the methods you want, like 'render', 'dispose', ...

Comment: cannon.getCannon() returns with a sprite. sb is a SpriteBatch. So it's the same as sprite.draw(spritebatch).

Comment: You are using 2 spritebatches, one in the render method and one in the class itself, delete the one in your render method. Also, you really need to think about implementing Screen instead of what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove SpriteBatch sb parameter from render method 
Just use like

```
@Override 
public void render()
```

Comment: If I remove the SpriteBatch sb, I get a red underline on the top 'playstate extends...' line and a red underline on the @overrride. If I remove the create() method I get no problems.

Comment: can you just write sb to render . delete "spritebatch" part.if it doesnt work then delete as my answer and also delete from state class and just use render()

Comment: it just crashes the application :/

Answer (score 0):

May be libgdx cannot draw sprites because duplicating any SpriteBatch.begin();
and duplicating SpriteBatch.end();
in stack of calls